# pandas.read_csv: how to skip comment lines

Tags: python, pandas

I think I misunderstand the intention of read_csv. If I have a file 'j' like

```
# notes
a,b,c
# more notes
1,2,3
```

How can I pandas.read_csv this file, skipping any '#' commented lines? I see in the help 'comment' of lines is not supported but it indicates an empty line should be returned. I see an error

```
df = pandas.read_csv('j', comment='#')
```

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 3

I'm currently on

```
In [15]: pandas.__version__
Out[15]: '0.12.0rc1'
```

On version'0.12.0-199-g4c8ad82':

```
In [43]: df = pandas.read_csv('j', comment='#', header=None)
```

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 3

Comment: What is `'j'`? I'm unable to reproduce the error when replacing `'j'` with csv file path.

Comment: Have your tried `df = pandas.read_csv('j', comment='#')`

Comment: Sorry, b'#' was a typo. 'j' is an example file. It is a bug as Andy Hayden mentions below.

Comment: @mathtick weirdly I get slightly different error with the above code, but I've [posted an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4623) with the CParserError you describe on github, I think it's a bug.

Comment: @AndyHayden ... yes, I grabbed the error from a loading a different file than shown in the example when I was in a rush. Just tried to reproduce it at home and discovered that the behavoiur appears to have already changed slightly the newer versions (tested on '0.12.0-199-g4c8ad82'). I've updated the example.

Comment: @mathtick I think should move the discussion to github (since it's a bug), header/commented first rows is the problem. :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

So I believe in the latest releases of pandas (version 0.16.0), you could throw in the `comment='#'` parameter into `pd.read_csv` and this should skip commented out lines.

These github issues shows that you can do this:

- https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10548
- https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4623

See the documentation on `read_csv`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: What happens if I have more than 1 comment character? I found a data file which is a dump from java and it has `#` for comment lines and `@` for block names and I want to skip both. In `gnuplot` I could set `#@` as comment chars and it skipped both but in pandas it gives a error saying only single character is allowed.

Answer (score 21):

One workaround is to specify skiprows to ignore the first few entries:

```
In [11]: s = '# notes\na,b,c\n# more notes\n1,2,3'

In [12]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',', comment='#', skiprows=1)
Out[12]: 
    a   b   c
0 NaN NaN NaN
1   1   2   3
```

Otherwise `read_csv` gets a little confused:

```
In [13]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',', comment='#')
Out[13]: 
        Unnamed: 0
a   b            c
NaN NaN        NaN
1   2            3
```

*This seems to be the case in 0.12.0, I've filed [a bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4623).*

As Viktor points out you can use dropna to remove the NaN after the fact... (there is a [recent open issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4466) to have commented lines be ignored completely):

```
In [14]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s2), comment='#', sep=',').dropna(how='all')
Out[14]: 
   a  b  c
1  1  2  3
```

*Note: the default index will "give away" the fact there was missing data.*

Comment: And also since you don't want the comment lines just call `.dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)` after.

Answer (score 5):

I am on Pandas version 0.13.1 and this *comments-in-csv* problem still bothers me.

Here is my present workaround:

```
def read_csv(filename, comment='#', sep=','):
    lines = "".join([line for line in open(filename) 
                     if not line.startswith(comment)])
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(lines), sep=sep)
```

Otherwise with `pd.read_csv(filename, comment='#')` I get

> pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 16, saw 3.