# Pandas CSV treats comment# character as a column.

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file with the header commented. I want to read it with pandas csv. Although pandas treat the # as a column. How do I solve this problem using pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas.read\_csv: how to skip comment lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366797/pandas-read-csv-how-to-skip-comment-lines)

Comment: @pritesh: I hope you  got what you are looking from the posted link!!